# nginx isn´t executing php file

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm running nginx on my dedicated root server and have multiple wordpress sites on it.

Additionally I want to update my private IP through an PHP script. For this reason I created this PHP File (myscript.php):

```
<?php    
    $pwort = 'mypassword';
    $port = ':80';

    $dyntxt = "my_IP.txt";
    $pworttest = $_GET["pass"];
    $IP = $_GET["meineip"];

    if (file_exists($dyntxt)){
        if($pworttest==$pwort) {
            $a = fopen("$dyntxt", "w");
            $dynamicip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            fwrite($a, $IP);
            fclose($a);
        } 
        else {
            $a = fopen("$dyntxt", "r+"); 
            $dynamicip = fread($a,filesize($dyntxt));
            fclose($a);

            $url="http://".$dynamicip."".$port; 
            header("Location: $url");
        }
    }
?>
```

And here is my config for dyn.myserver.co on nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/dyn;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name dyn.myserver.co;

    location / {
        try_files $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/dyn;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The IP which is written in myIP.txt is copied to the DNS Server by cronjob. That is working.
For example: On my apache server i called the dyndns URL (http://dyn.myserver.co/myscript.php) and was redirected to the IP which was filled in myIP.txt. On nginx it just shows me the content of myscript.php.

service php5-fpm status gives:

```
root@host01:/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d# service php5-fpm status
● php5-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php5-fpm.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-07-11 16:08:54 CEST; 3 days ago
  Process: 495 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/php5/php5-fpm-checkconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 613 (php5-fpm)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 3, Requests: 3294, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/php5-fpm.service
           ├─  613 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
           ├─  677 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─ 1486 php-fpm: pool www
           └─23693 php-fpm: pool www

Jul 11 16:08:52 host01 systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
Jul 11 16:08:54 host01 systemd[1]: Started The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
```

I think it's a problem with the nginx config. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does `my_IP.txt` are located on the same folder with your PHP script? if not it will give blank page and not redirecting because `file_exists($dyntxt)` is `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this on site-available folder

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/dyn;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name dyn.myserver.co;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Then you must link that file to site-enabled folder

`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com`

And restart nginx service

Comment: I just put this config in, made ln -s and restarted nginx. Now calling dyn.myserver.co/myscript.php gives 404 Not Found... Any ideas?

Comment: can you go inside `/run/php` and tell me if `php5-fpm.sock` exist in there?

Comment: I have edited the configuration, try paste it and restart nginx.. and see what happen

Comment: The file php5-fpm.sock doesn´t exist. This config redirects this call: dyn.myserver.co/myscript.php to one of my wordpress installations.

Comment: Have you install PHP 5.x ?

Comment: yes but sorry php5-fpm.sock does exist. I think the path in the config file was wrong. It was fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock; but it should be fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
Now i´m getting a white site when calling dyn.myserver.co/myscript.php
But i think it´s not working at all... The Link does not redirect to the IP of the FritzBox

Comment: It would be better to test your server with a simple code like `<?php echo("Hello"); ?>` while installing new server...

Comment: I´ve put a file "test.php" with  `<?php echo("Hello"); ?>` into `/var/www/dyn`. While running your posted config it just shows me a white site without any error message.

Comment: Hmm I'm using php7 maybe it have different settings with yours.. try put `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` above `include fastcgi_params;`

Comment: Or replace `include fastcgi_params;` with `include fastcgi.conf;`

Comment: Both configs show the "Hello" while calling dyn.myserver.co/test.php so thats working. But when i call my script it´s showing the content of that script so it´s not executing it. Is something in my php script not compatible?

Comment: That's mean the nginx now executing the PHP script. Now you need to show the error log from `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` or see the error on `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: At /var/log/nginx/error.log are messages like this:
`2017/07/15 12:46:23 [error] 32551#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.101.92.114, server: dyn.myserver.co, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "dyn.myserver.co"`

Comment: There´re no new entries after i call dyn.myserver.co/myscript.php. It still shows the code instead of executing it.

Comment: It should be logic error, please re check your code.. and write your code like `if (file_exists($dyntxt)){...} else {echo("File not exist!");}`

Comment: Solved by adding `<?php` at the beginning of my script... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem...

Thats my scipt:

```
<?    
    $pwort = 'mypassword';
    $port = ':80';

    $dyntxt = "my_IP.txt";
    $pworttest = $_GET["pass"];
    $IP = $_GET["meineip"];

    if (file_exists($dyntxt)){if($pworttest==$pwort) { $a = fopen("$dyntxt", "w");
    $dynamicip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    fwrite($a, $IP);
    fclose($a); } 
    else { $a = fopen("$dyntxt", "r+"); 
    $dynamicip = fread($a,filesize($dyntxt));
    fclose($a);

    $url="http://".$dynamicip."".$port; 
    header("Location: $url");} }
?>
```

But it has to be:

```
<?php    
    $pwort = 'mypassword';
    $port = ':80';

    $dyntxt = "my_IP.txt";
    $pworttest = $_GET["pass"];
    $IP = $_GET["meineip"];

    if (file_exists($dyntxt)){if($pworttest==$pwort) { $a = fopen("$dyntxt", "w");
    $dynamicip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    fwrite($a, $IP);
    fclose($a); } 
    else { $a = fopen("$dyntxt", "r+"); 
    $dynamicip = fread($a,filesize($dyntxt));
    fclose($a);

    $url="http://".$dynamicip."".$port; 
    header("Location: $url");} }
?>
```

Many thanks to @StefansArya for your effort!

Comment: Hi, please put this in your question by edit it.. before someone downvote your question and don't get any help at all..

Comment: I have edit your code some hours ago but looks like it wasn't reach you http://i63.tinypic.com/zx1744.jpg